# Getting Blob data from content document using File Sync

Tags: contentdocument, blob

So im using File Sync to upload an excel file to salesforce in order to use it in other class ive built (the class is reading the csv file and insert the data to salesforce - that one works fine uploading the file manually).
Ive managed to create a trigger that invoke on each document synchronizing\uploading to salesforce.
The problem is - the content document object doesnt have a "Body" \ "ContentData" field.
Ive tried to call a "FeedItem" or a "ContentDocumentFeed" record that holds that data but no record related to the content document record that been triggered is found.

Hope i managed to explain the situation and if anything comes to your mind i will be glad to hear it.

Thanks in advanced,
Noam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger can also be written on COntent Version .The content version object has field version Data and that holds data in base 64 encoded format .

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

[image]